# Making the game of Nim for a project

Tags: java

I have 3 problems when playing the smart computer.

- In `"Computer will take " + num`, `num` should equal how many the computer took, but currently, it just give me how much is left after its taken.
- When I hit 4 marbles left, the computer should then take only one or two, but it decides it can't do that, and just wins the game somehow.
- I'm not sure how to code one requirement. I don't know how to do the random legal move part if it's one less than a power of two minus 1.

  > In smart mode, the computer takes off enough marbles to make the size
  >   of the pile a power of two minus 1. That is always a legal move,
  >   except when the size of the pile is currently one less than a power of
  >   two, so in that case, make it create a random legal move.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int marbles = rand.nextInt(100) + 10;
int compMode = rand.nextInt(2) + 0; 
int takeaway = marbles;
boolean turn = rand.nextBoolean();

if (compMode == 1) {
  System.out.println("*** The computer is playing dumb.");
}
else {
  System.out.println("*** The computer is playing smart.");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("*** There are " + marbles + " marbles in the pile.");

while (marbles > 1) {
  if (turn == true){
    int ifBad = 0;
    while (ifBad == 0){
      System.out.print("How many do you want to take (1-" + marbles + ")");
      takeaway = scan.nextInt();
      int bad = marbles/2;
      if (takeaway > bad){
        System.out.println("Took too many marbles, try again");
      }
      else {
        ifBad++;
      }
    }
    marbles -= takeaway;
    System.out.println("*** There are " + marbles + " marbles in the pile.");
    turn = false;
  }
  if (turn == false){
    if (compMode == 1){
      marbles = getStupidMove(marbles, rand);
      System.out.println ("*** There are " + marbles + " marbles in the pile.");
    }
    else{
      marbles = getSmartMove(marbles); 
      System.out.println ("*** There are " + marbles + " marbles in the pile.");
    }
    turn = true;
  }
  if (marbles <= 1)
  {
    if (turn = false)
    {
      System.out.println ("Human Wins!");
    }  
    else
    {
      System.out.println ("Computer wins :(");
    }  
  }
}
```

```
public static int getSmartMove(int num){
  int power = 2;        
  while (power < num) 
  { 
    power *=2;
  }
  power /= 2;
  num = power-1;
  System.out.println("Computer will take " + num);

  return num;
}
```

```
public static int getStupidMove(int marbles, Random rand){
  int good = marbles/2;
  int take;
  if (marbles == 1){
    take = 1;
  }
  else {
    take = rand.nextInt(good) + 1;
    marbles -= take;
  }
  System.out.println("Computer will take " + take);
  return marbles; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question. It's normal to ask multiple questions while working on a single project like a game, this one should probably be asked as separate questions.

Comment: This is a bug: `if (turn = false)`. Should be `if (turn == false)`, or better yet, `if (!turn)`.

Comment: Yup, I found this one last night when troubleshooting a little bit, but thank you!

Comment: I do have another problem, no matter what happens, I can't win. The program, when there is 1 marble left, says it takes a marble, and then, doesn't actually take a marble, forcing me to take it.

Answer (score 0):

With your original code, the number taken away can be determined by subtracting the old amount of marbles from the new. Therefore, the old amount should be stored somewhere, or the new amount should be stored as a new variable.

```
int numNew = power-1;
System.out.println("Computer will take " + (num - numNew));
return numNew;
```

However, the code for retrieving the highest power of two can be simplified to just one function, `Integer.highestOneBit`. It finds the closest integer (less than or equal to a given value) that has only one bit set. If it has only one bit set, it means it is a power of two.

`int numNew = Integer.highestOneBit(num) - 1;`

---

To determine if an integer is a power of two, the amount of bits set can be counted with `Integer.bitCount`. Again, if only one bit is set, it's a power of two.

Since the check needs to be for one less than a power of two, the amount of bits for one higher than the current amount should be counted. If `num + 1` is a power of two, that means `num` is one less than a power of two.

```
if (Integer.bitCount(num + 1) == 1) {
    // Do some valid move.
    return getStupidMove(num, rand);
}
```

I'm not familiar with the rules of the game, but it appears a valid move is taking away anything less than half of the current amount of marbles. This seems to have been implemented in `getStupidMove`, so that can be returned.

---

When this hits 4 marbles left, it will successfully bring the marbles down to 3, since 4 is the closest power of two, and 3 is one less than that. However, contradictory to the instructions, you state it should take one or two. If you want this behaviour, you can add a check for when the marbles are 4 and define different behaviour.

Comment: well the check needs to be for one less than ONE LESS than a power of two for the stupid move. And that part confuses me.

Comment: In mathematical terms: if `x + 1 = y` then `x = y - 1` where `x` is the marbles and `y` is a power of two. When it is `y - 1` it means it is one less than a power of two.

Comment: Ya i misread my book, it works correctly. Sorry about that. Thanks so much!

Comment: Consider accepting and/or voting on the answer if you found it helpful.